# Jekyll does not evaluate liquid tags inside collections

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid

I have a `collection` in my `config.yml`. In this `collection` I have a list of `.md` files with their front matter. For example, I have this file called `paypal.md`:

```
---
title: "Paypal"
order: 1
paymentType: PAYPAL
name: paypal
---

blah blah blah, Content of the file...

<figure>
  <img src="{{site.baseurl}}/assets/images/paypal_logo.png">
</figure>
```

In another page, the main page, I want to render the content of the `paypal.md` (along with other pages) so here's what happens:

```
---
layout: page
title: "Payment Methods"
category: oth
order: 5
---

{% assign paypal = site.collection | where: "name", "paypal" | first  %}

{{paypal}}
```

The definitive output looks like this:

```
blah blah blah, Content of the file...

<figure>
  <img src="{{site.baseurl}}/assets/images/paypal_logo.png">
</figure>
```

The problem is, I can't render the image of the imported page because jekyll 
seems to be unable to parse `{{site.baseurl}}` that is the content of the imported collection.

I have tried with `{{paypal.content}}` (same result) and `{{paypal.output}}` (doesn't work at all).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that [Collections](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) are the right approach?

Imho this looks as if you want to include the same content into different pages, right?

For this you can use Includes which also allow you to pass Parameters:
[Documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#includes)

Comment: I think that Collections are the right approach, because I have a bunch of documents that are part of the same category and for all of them I have to memorize the same informations (codes, paths, images...) and some textual description. I wanted to use the textual description inside another page to describe these documents, but `{{}}` in these documents are not evaluated in the main page.. I'll try `include` however

Answer (score 0):

I just imported your templates and tried to reproduce the problem. I got not problem with it, the url was attached as expected. Are you sure, that the baseurl configuration is set?

Could you upload you project (or parts of it) somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, it is a corporate project, so I cannot upload it. 

I'll try to reproduce this in another git repo so you can see it, but this is not happening soon because I have a lot of work :/